# how does one create a school database with multiple years?

Tags: sql, database, postgresql

I'm making a mock school database I have a basic model on paper, but then when I thought about different dates and how to create the relation between semesters/quarters or even years things got extremely complicated, because it didn't make sense to have the same class in my classes table in multiple rows just with different dates. it'd be confusing, am I right? I did a quick google search on my problem and mostly got a method called a date dimension for my database. Not even sure if that is what I need.

Pretty much all I want is to organize/ set up relations between my tables to store multiple years of similar data,ie:a class with the same id but just different dates, different students, that only show up when i need a specific year or all years if required.

ATM my schema is looking like this.

```
students --table with all students
------------
student_id serial
first_name varchar(20)
last_name archer(20)

class -- bridge table 
------------
class_id  integer
class_name text
student_id integer
grade   varchar(2)

classes --table with all classes
------------
class_id serial
dept_id integer
class_name text

student_history --bridge table with a calander?
------------------
class_id integer
class_name text
grade    varchar(2)
```

Comment: `class_name` is redundant in `class`, it's already in `classes`. On your actual question, hat is important for you to model here? Can a student leave/join/switch classes during a year/semester? Do you intend to always have a fixed set of classes od can they vary in different years/semesters (e.g. because one year/semester there were way more students, than in the other,which forced useing more classes)?

Comment: all those extra features you've mentioned are nice but my main goal is to just record data, like what classes had what students, size of class isn't as important just for the example a realistic number between 30-50.  i just need to be able to query for a students past grades within a given date, what students were in a particular class at a specific time. simplest answer would just be to create a date column for my tables and query that way. I just thought as the database grew the more confusing it'd look

Answer (score 0):

I would so something like this:

```
-- this holds the students
create table student (id, name);

-- this holds the courses (for example, "Intro to CS", which is
-- offered every year)
 create table course (id, department_id, name);

-- this table shows what studends took which courses in which 
-- semesters, and what grade they got.  Because you have this, you
-- don't need a history table
create table enrollment (student_id, course_id, semester, grade)
```

It can get more complicated if you want to store things like "who taught the class", but this solves your immediate need.